# Can I deploy an app made in titanium to iphone from windows

Tags: titanium

I want to deploy app made in titanium studio in iphone from windows 7.Is it possible? If yes than how?

Comment: user did not give it search

Comment: a little google search doesn't hurt ([like](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/165644/is-there-a-way-to-publish-ios-app-from-windows-linux)).

Answer (score 0):

Somebody has asked me 100% same question 2 days ago.This was my answer

First Short answer:

No you cant compile iOS apps on windows machine.

Now reason:

The reason behind it is that titanium javascript code is ultimately converted to xcode project and xcode only works on mac machine and its not cross platform

Thanks